# Where is Archetype microbrewery in Vietnam?

Tags: breweries, craft-beers, local

Traveling to Vietnam in 2018-19 I had the chance to try several (very good!) local craft beers and one of those I tasted in Ho Chi Minh was by **Archetype Brewing Co.**

I am trying to find out any reference, for example the address of the brewery headquarters, or a company website, because neither Google Maps nor [RateBeer](https://www.ratebeer.com/brewers/archetype-brewing-co/40684/) and [Untappd](https://untappd.com/b/archetype-brewing-co-archetype-vietnam/2667220) seem to know where this brand of beer is produced.

Archetype Vietnam is not Archetype USA: https://www.ratebeer.com/search?q=Archetype&tab=brewer

Their logo:

[image: Logo]

Comment: How do you know it produced in Vietnam, meaning did you get a bottle of it and it was printed in Vietnamese or just pint glass. There are counterfeit beers in Vietnam.  Try contacting Pasteur street brewing, Saigon, they are local brewer and they may know about it if it is indeed brewed in HCM.

Comment: @AlaskaMan the three links in my question seem to confirm what they told me in several bars, that this is a local brand from somewhere in Vietnam :)

Answer (score 2):

**Where is Archetype microbrewery in Vietnam?**

Archetype microbrewery is a relatively new microbrewery (2019) situated in Ho Chi Minh City, Vietnam?

> [**Archetype No Name Pale Ale**](https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/archetype-no-name-pale-ale/755466/)
>
> Bottle at Biacraft District 1, Ho Chi Minh City. Poured a clear medium amber colour with a lasting frothy white head. The aroma is toffee caramel malt, light woody hop. The flavour is moderate sweet light bitter, with a smooth caramel malt, light fruity, light pepper spice, light dry woody hop bitter palate. Medium bodied with to soft carbonation.

[image]

Comment: Yes, Ken, thank you!! This is definitely it. I see the latest review although that is only about where the beer is served and, still, the location of the brewery is unknown :)

Comment: @MattAllegro Perhap you can communicate with  https://biacraft.com/ ,   as they seem to have had  it they may have more info on it.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I will do! Thanks. So I can add them to [**my list**](https://www.google.com/maps/placelists/list/m_z16-yl2cXnswv4RoPd_hoHGOPsoQ)! By the way, I had the luck to have a pint at BiaCraft and they rock. They have lots of different beers and surely know :)

Comment: @MattAllegro I see  Pasture Street Brewery on your list. +1  https://saigoneer.com/explore/sponsored-listings-gold-silver/6620-pasteur-street-brewing

Comment: @AlaskaMan ahaha Pasteur is one of those I enjoyed least ;) but the average quality and taste of (so many) craft beers from Vietnam is incredibly high. Seven Bridges and Roosters are IMHO outstanding good breweries for example :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this brewery is not local to Ho Chi Minh city at all but is based in North Carolina. The only brewery I can find with that name is https://archetypebrewing.com/ based out of Asheville. When I checked their "beer finder" with Ho Chi Minh City ( https://archetypebrewing.com/beer-finder/?fwp_beer_finder_proximity=10.8230989%2C106.6296638%2C10%2CHo%2520Chi%2520Minh%2520City%252C%2520Vietnam - direct link so sorry about the garbled URL ) it finds several locations in the city that sell their beer.

Comment: Hi! Thank you! I knew this one from the US, but I'm not sure it is the same: the logos are different and RateBeer lists both the brewer from Vietnam and the one from USA https://www.ratebeer.com/search?q=Archetype&tab=brewer